# Angular ng-repeat rating images

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two pngs, one with an empty star one with a full star. Depending on the ratings from 1-5 I want to add or remove more star images. Here is my code that doesn't work:

```
<div>
                        <img ng-repeat="i in getNumberOfFullStars(company.AverageReview)" ng-src="{{starPhoto}}">
                        <img ng-repeat="i in getNumberOfEmptyStars(company.AverageReview)" ng-src="{{emptyPhoto}}">
                    </div>
```

JS

```
$scope.getNumberOfFullStars = function(num){
        return new Array(num);
    };

    $scope.getNumberOfEmptyStars = function(num){
        var emptyCount = 5-num;
        return new Array(emptyCount);
    };
```

Any thoughts? Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of two seperate images, you can just use one and then check against $index. Modify to meet your needs

```
<div>
    <img data-ng-repeat="i in ratings" data-ng-src="{{ ($index < company.AverageReview) && starPhoto || emptyPhoto }}" />
</div>

$scope.ratings=[];
$scope.ratings.length = 5;
```

Comment: It repeats for me: http://jsfiddle.net/4wxY2/ you can check the html to see the images are there (even though their src is blank because I don't have your starPhoto or emptyPhoto)